# Unable to called mouse related event after perform Ajax for my div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to use the mouseenter or other related event. But my function wont trigger. First, I have a div called article and I use jquery to append, to design its inner. But the jquery wont fired anything up. If i have mouse over.

Then I revert back to the normal mouseover and mouseout using javascript also cant work. Please explain to me why this happen and how to work around it.

I will always empty my article and perform a AJAX reload. like google search box

```
<div id="article">  //Empty
</div>

var over = function (myObj) {
  alert("A");  //NOT FIRE
};

var out = function (myObj) {
};

$(".items").mouseenter(function() { alert("A"); //NOT Fire });


var myObject = JSON.parse(result, function (key, value) {

  if (key == "Name") name = value;
  if (key == "ProductId") id = value;
  if (key == "Url") {

    $("#article").append(
    "<div class='items left' onmouseover='over(this)' onmouseout='out(this)'>" +
     "<div class='clear' style='height: 2px;'></div>" +
   "</div>");
  }
}
```

//Note: After search in depth again. I realize it has something to do with delegate using on live from jquery. However, depsite that I am still unable to call those function

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.items',function() { 
  alert("A"); 
});
```

The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object.

Comment: Hi, i tried this code above. but the function still wont trigger. I have the the on before my window ready

Comment: what is`myObject `??and how are you gonna call it?how that will append?

Comment: Hi, for some reasons it works depending on the locate i place the code. I will do further test.

Comment: Oh. myObj is a function that is trigger after PageMethod (asp.net). It is just naming convers.   function myObj    ==   var myobj = fn()